# conflicting types for error for a function

Tags: c, pointers

In the project that I'm working on, there's some weird error regarding pointers.
I am not really sure what the problem is here.

The error says:

> conflicting types for 'undo_list'

```
Sudoku_Board* undo_list(Linked_List* list) {
    Sudoku_Board* sboard;

    if(list->current->prev == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    sboard = list->current->prev->sboard;
    list->current = list->current->prev;

    return sboard;
}
```

And in the header file I have the following:

```
typedef struct sudo_board {
    int block_row;
    int block_col;
    int** board;
    int fixed_num;
    int** fixed;
    int** current_solution;
    int mark_errors_flag;
    int** errors;
} Sudoku_Board;


typedef struct node {
    struct sudo_board* sboard;
    struct node* next;
    struct node* prev;
} Element;


typedef struct {
    Element* current;
    Element* tail;
} Linked_List;
```

I am using MinGW compiler

Comment: Your code is not enough to demonstrate the problem. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: You should point out where the error is, where `undo_list` is defined/declared, what compiler you use, etc.

Comment: Everything you need to see is here. undo_list is defined in listing.c while the header file is called listing.h and I included it

Comment: Is that the whole `listing.h`? Are you perhaps including another header that might declare `undo_list`?

Comment: Most of all, you need to show how undo_list is declared.

Answer (score 1):

The problem most probably is that you have a declaration of your function elsewhere whose signature does not match the one listed here.